# reading and writing to file in haskell

Tags: haskell, file-io

I'm trying to read a file  in haskell.

Originally I tried:

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

main = do
    let list = []
    handle <- openFile "data.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    let singlewords = words contents
        list = f singlewords
    print list
    hClose handle

f :: [String] -> [Int]
f = map read
```

I've since updated that to be:

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

main = do
    handle <- openFile "data.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    print contents
```

But, now the output looks like:

```
"hdhdhdhhdhdhd\n"
"hdhdhdhdhh\n"
```

I would like the output to look like:

```
hdhdhhdhhdhdhdhd
hdhdhhshshshshshshh
```

Comment: What exact code did you use, and with what file did you test it?

Comment: i try to use just the reading and printing the content of the file but i didnt work. so i used the whole code but still i get that error. this is the code i used : import System.IO  
import Control.Monad

main = do  
        let list = []
        handle <- openFile "data.txt" ReadMode
        contents <- hGetContents handle
        let singlewords = words contents
            list = f singlewords
        print list
        hClose handle   

f :: [String] -> [Int]
f = map read

Comment: @user3841581 Add that up in your original question. Also add the file contents which you are trying to read.

Comment: i have just managed to fix it. i have managed to read and print using this :import System.IO  
import Control.Monad

main = do  
       
        handle <- openFile "data.txt" ReadMode
        contents <- hGetContents handle
        print contents

Comment: but output of each line is in the format : hdhdhdhhdhdhd \n hdhdhdhdhh\n . how do i arrange  them nicely so that they are in this form:hdhdhhdhhdhdhdhd
hdhdhhshshshshshshh

Comment: @user3841581 Please edit your question with the appropriate information.  As of right now, it's very unclear what you're asking, what your problem is, or even what code you're using.  If you edit your question and add the code you're using, the file you're trying to read, and the exact error message you're getting in the text of your question, then I will vote to reopen your question and try to help you with your problem.  As of right now, I don't even know what your question is or what your goal is, so I am simply unable to provide you any assistance.

Comment: i have just managed to fix it. i have managed to read and print using this :import System.IO  
import Control.Monad

main = do  
       
        handle <- openFile "data.txt" ReadMode
        contents <- hGetContents handle
        print contents

Comment: i have a questions tough. how do i format is as different line because with print, i just have a string with \n appended on each line

Comment: @ bheklilr, here is what im trying to do. im trying to read a multi line file and print the content. this is the code i have used :import System.IO import Control.Monad main = do handle <- openFile "data.txt" ReadMode contents <- hGetContents handle print contents  . now i can print the whole content but as a string with each line appended with a \n. how can print it like its original format. sorry for the poor formulation of the question. i am very new in programming

Comment: @user3841581 If you have a question, please put it _in your question_, not the comments.  Without a clear question to answer your post does not follow the Stackoverflow guidelines, which is why your question has been closed.  If you're wanting some beginner material on Haskell, I would recommend reading [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), which I've found to be a great introduction to the language.

Comment: @user3841581 I see what your problem is but I will not answer it until it is in the proper format for SO. Additionally, being new to programming does not excuse you from asking a question in the correct format. Please locate the "Edit" button on this post and add your code and question there. We are very willing to help you with your problem, but you also have to be willing to meet the requirements put forward by this forum. These rules were put into place to keep the quality of this site high so that beginners like yourself can find help easily, but "easy" does not mean without effort.

Comment: @bheklilr *I* edited the question so it's at least understandable what is being asked.  It's still not a great question, but it might at least be deserving of an answer.

Comment: i have figured it out.Thank you. i will try to be more clearer next time. sorry agaion for the poor formating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is explainable by the function `f = map read`.  This function attempts to convert a list of strings into a list of ints by parsing the individual strings as integer values.  Since your file contained `hdhdhdhdhdhdhd\nhdhdhdhdhdhh`, none of those characters were even digits and you were getting an error saying that `read` failed to parse them to `Int`s.

The second problem you had, once you removed the parsing stage so as to just perform the file read was that you were using `print` to output the text to the screen, whereas the appropriate function to use here is `putStr` or `putStrLn`.  The difference is that `print` is defined as `print x = putStrLn (show x)`, so it automatically converts a value to its string representation before putting it to the screen.  When you already have a `String`, say the string `x = "hello"`, the output from `show x` is `"\"hello\""`, so it includes the quotes and any other escaped characters.  This is so that `read (show x) == x`, where `read` parses a string as if it were defined in source code, i.e. between double quotes and with escape characters as appropriate.  Therefore, you should simply use `putStrLn` when you wish to print a `String` to the screen, and `print` when you want to print a non-string value to the screen, such as an `Int`.